# Filter uitable content by user parameters

Tags: matlab, datetime, datatable

I need some help. I have loaded large amount of data 52500x9 from .xlsx into UITable(whole year dataset 10min sampling period)component. I need to filter these data by date via DatePicker is it possible ? for example I want to display values from 1.1.2018 - to 12.1.2018

Here is how input looks like

```
enter code here
```

[image: input table]

Comment: Can you share a small example dataset that we can use? Provide code and not screenshots, thanks.

Comment: [link] https://ufile.io/ss3cx hope it helps. I am all at sea